# ScaLAPACK in C++ - pdlaprnt() - Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: c++, scalapack

I'm trying to write a program in C++, using ScaLAPACK directly. In that way, I'm calling its functions through `extern "C"` block and it's working, until I came around [PDLAPRNT()](https://netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d0/da9/pdlaprnt_8f_source.html) function, i.e. a printing of `double` arrays.

When I'm trying to run it to print a simple 9-element-long array, I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/mpirun --oversubscribe -n 6 ./ex3print
Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Memory allocation failure in xrealloc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[10150,1],0]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Do you have any idea, what I'm doing wrong? I guess, my "mapping" of the original FORTRAN function is incorrect, but I have no idea why.**

---

#### FORTRAN Signature

```
SUBROUTINE pdlaprnt( M, N, A, IA, JA, DESCA, IRPRNT, ICPRNT, CMATNM, NOUT, WORK )
```

Where, `M`, `N`, `IA`, `JA`, `IRPRNT`, `ICPRNT` and `NOUT` are of type `INTEGER`, `A` and `WORK` are `DOUBLE PRECISION` arrays, `DESCA` is an `INTEGER` array and finally `CMATNM` is of type `CHARACTER*(*)`.

---

#### My C++ "interface"

```
extern void pdlaprnt_(int *m, int *n, double *A, int *iA, int *jA, int *descA, int *irprnt, int *icprnt, char *cmatnm,
                      int *nout, double *work);
```

---

### My code

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
extern void sl_init_(int *ictxt, int *nprow, int *npcol);
extern void blacs_gridexit_(int *ictxt);
extern void blacs_gridinfo_(int *ictxt, int *nprow, int *npcol, int *myrow, int *mycol);
extern void blacs_exit_(int *cont);
extern void descinit_(int *desc, int *m, int *n, int *mb, int *nb, int *rsrc, int *csrc, int *ictxt, int *mxllda,
                      int *info);
extern void pdlaprnt_(int *m, int *n, double *A, int *iA, int *jA, int *descA, int *irprnt, int *icprnt, char *cmatnm,
                      int *nout, double *work);
}

/* BLACS context handle */
int ictxt = 0;

/* Number of rows and columns of the process grid */
int nprow = 2;
int npcol = 3;

/* Row and column indices in a process grid */
int myrow, mycol;

/* Row and column block size */
int mb = 2;
int nb = 2;
int nbrhs = 1;

/* Array descriptors for the global matrices */
int* descB = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * mb);

/* Number of right-hand sides b */
int nrhs = 1;

/* Process row and column over which the first row of the array A is distributed */
int rsrc = 0;
int csrc = 0;

/* Leading dimension of the local array */
int mxlldb = 5;

/* Allocate b array */
double* b = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * mxlldb);

/* Return code */
int info;

/* BLACS continue code */
int continue_code = 0;

int main(){
    /* Initialize the process grid */
    sl_init_(&ictxt, &nprow, &npcol);
    blacs_gridinfo_(&ictxt, &nprow, &npcol, &myrow, &mycol);

    /* Initialize array descriptors */
    descinit_(descB, &nb, &nrhs, &nb, &nbrhs, &rsrc, &csrc, &ictxt, &mxlldb, &info);

    /* Init b vector */
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        b[i] = 6;
    }

    int iB = 1, jB = 1;
    double* work = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * mxlldb);
    int irprnt = 0;
    int icprnt = 0;
    char* cmatnm = (char*)"B";
    int nout = 6;

    /* Print RHS b */
    pdlaprnt_(&nb, &nrhs, b, &iB, &jB, descB, &irprnt, &icprnt, cmatnm, &nout, work);

    /* Free BLACS context */
    blacs_gridexit_(&ictxt);

    /* Exit BLACS */
    blacs_exit_(&continue_code);

    return 0;
}
```